# AWS CloudFormation templates: how to get templates info?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to get AWS CloudFormation templates schema info in some technical format? There's a documentation provided here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html
I would like to get all information for all templates in some technical format. I could scrape official documentation but I believe there should be better way. Is there better way?

Comment: Found their current documentation (Jan. 2019). Doesn't list all options, but the template-anatomy section gives at least their required components and required order: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-formats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution, but other people have done this before you, so you could use what they've done. [Here's one example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cfndsl/cfndsl/master/lib/cfndsl/aws/resource_specification.json).

Comment: Please provide some context for the link. Otherwise your answer will not make any sense in case the linked page disappears.

Comment: From what I see currently there's no official templates schema in any tech format. So, yes, it seems that reusing cfndsl schemas is what I can use. Thank you.